# Mercurial on windows and ssh configuration with Copssh problem

Tags: mercurial, ssh

I've installed the copssh on a windows 2008 server and then I tried to clone a reposity on the server through ssh. But no matter how hard I tried I couldn't fix this error i got. here is the log:

```
C:\Users\Admin>hg clone ssh://ehsan@rafsanjani.ir
The authenticity of host 'rafsanjani.ir (96.31.90.174)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 41:a8:41:21:61:1a:67:2c:e8:44:99:6c:63:e7:06:73.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
ehsan@rafsanjani.ir's password:
remote: Could not create directory '/home/Administrator/.ssh'.
remote: Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/Administrator/.ssh/known_hosts).
remote: /bin/bash: Permission denied
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

I tried to login with administrator but i get the same error message. Also i changed the permission of the folder located in C:\Program Files (x86)\ICW\home\administrator so that ehsan has the full access to this folder.

also when I connect to the server with putty and use this command:

```
cd /home/administrator/.ssh 
echo test>test
```

file test will create! so it seems that I have the permission to this folder!

this is log when i try to clone with administrator account:

```
C:\Users\Admin>hg clone ssh://administrator@rafsanjani.ir
The authenticity of host 'rafsanjani.ir (96.31.90.174)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 41:a8:41:21:61:1a:67:2c:e8:44:99:6c:63:e7:06:73.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
administrator@rafsanjani.ir's password:
remote: Could not create directory '/home/Administrator/.ssh'.
remote: Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/Administrator/.ssh/known_hosts).
remote: bash: hg: command not found
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

Comment: Have you consider to ask this question at superuser.com or serverfault.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest versions of copssh/cwrsync use cygwin 1.7 and require a HOME environment variable. So just add a HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% variable and it should work right away. It did for me :)

Comment: where do i add this variable? I'm a little newbe

Comment: Control Panel -> System -> Advanced Tab -> Environment Variables or right-click on the computer's icon and select Properties. That works on XP; Win2008 Server might be slightly different.